# Test authentication redirect using Devise and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capybara, rspec-rails

I have a sample Rails app that I'm working on so I can start getting familiar with BDD.

Right now I'm using Devise to handle my user authentication.

I have a Task model which requires a user to be logged in in order to access the new, create, edit, and destroy actions.

I have the following code:

**requests/tasks_spec.rb**

```
describe "Tasks" do

  it "redirects to sign in for new task if no user logged in" do
    visit new_task_path
    response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
  end

end
```

Now when I run this test, I expect it to fail because I haven't added any before_filter logic to TasksController.  I run the test and it fails.

Now I add the `authenticate_user!` helper provided by Devise.

**tasks_controller.rb**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :destroy]
  ...
end
```

The tests run and still fails, saying the following:

```
  1) TasksController redirects to sign in for new task if no user logged in
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
       Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>
```

Now when calling visit, since no user was established in the session, I expect the response to be redirected to /user/sign_in.  However, I simply get a 200OK back.

What am I missing here?  How do I get this test to pass?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
describe "redirects to sign in for new task if no user logged in" do
  before { post tasks_path }
  specify { response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path) }
end
```